# Bind: Overwrite one host of foreign domain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Our customer has a domain. Let's call it example.com.

We are running a VM in the network of our customer. Let's call it "our-vm".

The customer is accessing the vm with this name: our-vm.example.com.

The IP address is an internal for example 10.1.2.3

The name server of our customer (example.com) does not resolve the host name.

We have a VPN to our customer and are able to access 10.1.2.3 via IP address.

But I would like to access the host by name.

What I want:

- our-vm.example.com should get resolved by me (running a bind in our network)
- www.example.com, mail.example.com and other names should get resolved by example.com

How to configure bind this way?

Sub-question: is there a name for this type of configuration?

This is not a duplicate of ([Overriding some DNS entries in BIND for internal networks](https://serverfault.com/questions/18748/overriding-some-dns-entries-in-bind-for-internal-networks)) because I want example.com to be handled by the customer.

Comment: And the term you're looking for is "DNS masquerade"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your BIND configuration, include something like this:

```
zone "example.com" {
  type forward;
  forwarders { x.x.x.x; y.y.y.y; };
};

zone "our-vm.example.com" {
  type master;
  file "/var/named/db/our-vm.example.com";
};
```

That should do the trick.

**Edit:** Apparently the correct term is, according to Jenny D, "DNS masquerade".