# Overriding a .local Domain to a Public IP

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind, local, rpz

I am using a BIND9 DNS server for my org, and I have an application that was published with a .local domain: example.website.local. There is an .com alternative that I want to re-map the .local to using the DNS server, but I don't know if it will be possible.

I have found this article on RPZ: [Overriding some DNS entries in BIND for internal networks](https://serverfault.com/questions/18748/overriding-some-dns-entries-in-bind-for-internal-networks), but I keep getting this message after I apply the setting with my .local domain:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> example.website.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 61184
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.website.local.     IN  A

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Sun Oct 17 11
```

Is there a way to rewrite this **.local** domain to a **.com** or public IP address using BIND or RPZ?

Thanks!

Comment: use hosts /etc/hosts to do the trick

Comment: Thanks @djdomi /etc/hosts does work for the local machines. I ended up using RPZ to solve the issue. 

This is apparently also called a 'DNS firewall' but I used it to re-map the DNS lookups for the specific example.local domain.

Comment: Here is a quick run-down of what I needed to do to get it to work:

1. Have a working BIND9 server on a debian/Ubuntu box
2. Edit the `named.conf.options` file
`response-policy { 
    zone "rpz.local"; 
};
`
3. Add the RPZ zone in the `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` file
`zone "rpz.local" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.rpz.local";
    allow-query { localhost; };
    allow-transfer { 12.34.56.78; };
};`

4. copy /etc/bind/db.empty to /etc/bind/db.rpz.local
5. Add the A record the .local to the db.rpz.local file
`example.local      A      8.8.8.8`
6. restart DNS

Comment: Update your question, not the comment....!!!!! Or of its solved, use an Answer to solve your question

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick run-down of what I needed to do to get it to work:

1. Have a working BIND9 server on a debian/Ubuntu box
2. Edit `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` adding:

```
response-policy { 
    zone "rpz.local"; 
};
```

3. Add the RPZ zone in `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`

```
zone "rpz.local" { 
    type master; 
    file "/etc/bind/db.rpz.local"; 
    allow-query { localhost; }; 
    allow-transfer { localhost; }; 
};
```

4. copy `/etc/bind/db.empty` to `/etc/bind/db.rpz.local`
5. Add the A record the .local to `db.rpz.local` file:

```
example.local A 8.8.8.8
```

6. restart DNS

```
systemctl restart bind9
rndc flush
rndc reload
```